# Multiple similar loop in a view, better practice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using Rails 3. I have 2 options for my view:

**OPTION A:**

```
<% @items.each do |item| %>
  ...
<% end %>
...

<script>
  var items = [
    <% @items.each do |item| %>
      ['<%= item.name %>', <%= item.lat %>, <%= item.lng %>],
    <% end %>
  ];
</script>
```

**OPTION B:**

```
<% @items.each do |item| %>
  ...
  <% content_for :items_array do %>
    ['<%= item.name %>', <%= item.lat %>, <%= item.lng %>],
  <% end %>
<% end %>
...

<script>
  var items = [<%= yield :items_array %>];
</script>
```

At the moment, I have chosen **OPTION B**, but I still think that it is not neat at all. Any better way to do this? I refused to choose **OPTION A** because I don't want it to loop twice in the same view because of performance and DRY issues, correct me if I am wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you putting Ruby code in javascript?

Comment: Getting the latitude and longitude for Google Maps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it were my project I would probably move this problem to the javascript side. Put the lat and long into data- attributes somewhere in the item tags and use unobtrusive scripting to read them. (If you want an example let me know.)

If that's not possible, I personally would prefer option A, first of all for readability (it's easier to understand, especially if you're not familiar with content_for) and second because it's easier to refactor, we could move collecting the data into a method on the model or maybe into a helper. DRY doesn't really apply here because even though you're looping through the same dataset, you're doing very different things with it.

That said, I wasn't quite sure about the performance implications so I ran a little test. I took 500 client records in one of my apps and used the option A to render a list of links followed by mapping their data into a content_for block and benchmarked it using Ruby's inbuilt Benchmark module (it's in haml instead of erb but I'm sure it's not too hard to read.)

```
- bench = Benchmark.measure do
  %ul#client-list
    - @clients.each do |client|
      %li
        = link_to client.company, client
        - content_for :foobar do
          = "['#{j client.name}', '#{j client.company}', '#{j client.email}'],"

  = javascript_tag do
    var nearbys = [#{yield :foobar}];

%p= bench.to_s
```

The result, about 370 miliseconds

```
 0.370000 0.000000 0.370000 ( 0.397476)
```

Then I did the same with two loops (one `each` one `map`):

```
- bench = Benchmark.measure do
  %ul#client-list
    - @clients.each do |client|
      %li
        = link_to client.company, client

  = javascript_tag do
    = "var nearbys = [#{ @clients.map { |client| "['#{j client.name}', '#{j client.company}', '#{j client.email}']," }}]"

%p= bench.to_s
```

The results, about 80 miliseconds:

```
0.080000 0.000000 0.080000 ( 0.077940)
```

You may want to check the results yourself, but it seems like the content_for method is not a very efficient means to solve this problem.

edit: just for reference, this was tested using ree 1.8.7 and rails 3.2.6

edit2:

An example of how to rewrite this without using inline javascript. I'd first move all the required parameters into `data-` attributes, for example in the view:

```
<% @items.each do |item| %>
  <div class="item" data-name="<%= item.name %>"
                    data-lat="<%= item.lat %>"
                    data-long="<%= item.long %>">
    <%= item.name %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

(You could also take the name from inside the div, but putting everything in data-attributes is more consistent.)

Then in you javascript you could map the data as follows (assuming jquery):

```
var nearbys = $('.item').map(function() {
  return [ $(this).data("name"), $(this).data("lat"), $(this).data("long") ];
});
```

This way you can keep all your javascript neatly in a separate file and collecting the data is done client-side.

Comment: +1 for the data-attribute idea. But please use `escape_javascript(...)` (alias is `j(...)`) otherwise you will run into problems if you have names like O'Connell, another thing is that you'll have an extra comma on the end of your array list which could cause problems in certain browsers. That's why someone invented JSON :)

Comment: Yes good point. It was a quick and dirty test but you should of course always escape your javascript. I'll edit the answer, thanks! And we should strip the extra comma too or use json (also a good point ;)) but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader :p

Comment: Thanks for the benchmark. I have tried to benchmark mine, results for Option A and B appear to be the same (90ms), except that for the first run, it goes up to (270ms). Is it because of cache? By the way, would you mind to give an example how you would refactor this? Thanks.

Comment: Sure, added an example at the bottom of my post. Hope it helps!

Comment: Never mind mate, I can just refer to this http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript?view=asciicast to learn about data attributes.

Comment: Just realized you added an example! Thanks so much. There's a typo: `$('.item')`. I still need to modify your example to fix something, but it's really a good head-start. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

it's very simple just use `to_json` it will do all the escaping for you ;)

So your code could look like this:

```
<script>
  var items = <%= @items.map{|o| [o.name, o.lat, o.lng]}.to_json.html_safe %>;
</script>
```

(the html_safe marks the string as safe, avoiding double escaping)

If you have objects that are more complex than just arrays of strings and numbers you should use jQuery's `$.parseJSON(json)` so it would look like:

```
<script>
  var items = $.parseJSON('<%= @items.map{|o| [o.name, o.lat, o.lng]}.to_json.html_safe %>');
</script>
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks, it's a pretty good option. I will learn up data attributes instead, seems like a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

All of this code should go into a function in the helper file for the Model. That is what the helpers are for, right?

**The views should have minimum Ruby code hard-wired into them**. So, *use helpers*.

Here are some links to get you more insight into helpers:

- [using-helper-methods-in-ruby-on-rails](http://paulsturgess.co.uk/articles/49-using-helper-methods-in-ruby-on-rails)
- [what-belongs-in-a-helper-method](http://37signals.com/svn/posts/1108-what-belongs-in-a-helper-method)